# Is prop method by jQuery suppose to be supported by IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, prop

I couldn't find any reference in any documentation to the support of jQuery method by the different browsers.

When I run the following code:

```js
var c = $("#textValue");
c.attr("style", "background-color: yellow");
c.prop("style", "background-color: green");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span id="textValue" style="background-color: red;">Hello world</span>
</div>
```

In chrome I get a green background color and in IE I get the yellow color.
Does anyone know where I can read better documentation of browsers support? as it seem to not be available in the original jQuery documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Which IE version are you using? If `IE` <= 9, read before the **example** [Additional Notes for IE 9 or lower](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-examples). DOM element still exist, will no overwrited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, `style` is not a property, it is an attribute, so using `$.prop` is incorrect, if you want to set it, using `$.attr` is the correct way to go.

Why Chrome will handle a mistake like this differently, I cannot say. Internet Explorer is correct in ignoring your attempt to set the style using `prop`.

- The difference between attributes and properties is explained here in the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value
- jQuery supports Internet Explorer from version 9 onwards, as documented here: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Thanks. I Never made a difference between attribute and property, I thought of them as the same. Now I will need to go over my code and make sure it is correct.
Thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help! If you want to style jQuery elements, I think `$.css` is an even better choice https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Comment: No, I read somewhere that prop replace attr and since I was in a version higher than 1.6 which was mentioned I thought it would be ok to switch all references from attr to prop - and then I didn't understand why my code broke :(